# Schedule a job to dynamically kill a (truss) process after a minute?

Tags: kill, scheduling, truss

I have been trying to accomplish a simple scheduled task in Solaris 11 with the use of the `at` command.

Example:

```
$> kill $(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep truss | awk '{print $2}') | at now + 1 minute; truss -fp 1706 &
```

Anyone have any insight?

Comment: At wants a command line as input; you've provided the output of kill (which is likely an empty string) as its input. You can probably do something much simpler, like `(sleep 60; pkill truss)& `

Comment: That is much more elegant. Thanks. I never use pkill.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should instead have a look at the [`timeout`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout) command.